# Recover Machine Key that was not marked as exportable upon creation

Tags: c#, security, iis, cryptography

We have a machine key that is located in: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` that was probably generated using the command `aspnet_regiis "MyKey" -pc`. The key works fine although we want to export it. The problem is the key wasn't marked as exportable when it was initially created, it should have been created using this `aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKey" -exp` so that we could export it in the future.

When we run `aspnet_regiis.exe -px "MyKey" C:\exported.xml -pri` we get the error: `key not valid for use in specified state` which we understand to mean it wasn't marked as exportable when it was created.

Is there a way we can recover the private key, perhaps there is an application we can write in C# to run on the server?

Comment: It's impossible to distinguish between "someone forgot to use `-exp` switch" and "someone tried to hack a system", so the designers of Windows cryptography ensure that the keys cannot be exported if they were not initially marked as exportable. With that in mind, what kind of answers are you looking for?

Comment: @lexli - my thought was that the private key is on the machine and although it's not easily accessible it must be physically accessible if there is no cryptographic reason that it is not.

Comment: mimikatz tool can do this, be aware that most antiviruses will block it as it's heavily used by white and black hat hackers. You cannot do this using any normal API, Windows just completely blocks this all the way down to lsass.exe. mimikatz can pull data out of lsass using some special hacks.

Comment: @charlieface - that's interesting and exactly what I'm after! I would be happy for you to put that as the answer if you know what the commands would be to execute.

Comment: [so] not really the place for this. Prob best migrated to [su] or [sf]. Anyway plenty of info if you google it https://gitbook.seguranca-informatica.pt/credentials-exfiltration/extracting-certs-private-keys-from-windows-using-mimikatz-and-intercepting-calls-with-burpsuite